# the way the dropdown looks is changing when form-control class is used - Angular

Tags: angular, form-control, nebular, ngx-admin

I'm using ngx-admin template which used nebular theme

I am working dropdown validation. For that I'm using `class="form-control"`. The way the dropdown looks is changing when i use form control class.

If form control is used, it looks like this.

[image: label with dropdown]

Without form-control, it looks like

[image]

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="title" class="label col-sm-3 form-control-label">Title :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
       <nb-select  id="title" formControlName="titleName" (change)="changeTitle($event)" placeholder="Select" >
         <nb-option *ngFor="let title of Title" [value]="title">{{title}}</nb-option>
       </nb-select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also help me with dropdown validation. I not achieving it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using material, but inspect the styles behind the form-control attribute. Maybe it has some padding. 
A simple solution is overriding that selector in css.

Good luck!